# Работа с VK API (Android) использование запроса

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Как правильно написать запрос для получения списка друзей пользователя по ID.
Делал так:

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
String userID = "000000000";

VKRequest request = VKApi.friends().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_IDS, userID));
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        VKList list = (VKList) response.parsedModel;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
});
```

В результате ничего, или закрывается приложение.

Comment: Без сообщения об ошибке, её типе и конкретной строки её возникновения помочь вам никак нельзя. И уведомлять адаптер об изменениях надо после установки его в ListView